# MySQL SORT BY starting from specific result position?

Tags: mysql

I have a set of data within a database as follows:

```
id | name    | price | balance
-------------------------------
1  | john    | 100   | 40
2  | dave    | 50    | 29
3  | steven  | 29    | 200
4  | mike    | 482   | 19
5  | clare   | 21    | 102
```

I want to grab the results from this database and `ORDER BY` balance in descending order. *(highest balance first)* - though I want the result set to start at the X position, for this sake lets say we want the results after the **third position**, so the first two results should not show.

This should be the result of the query:

```
id | name    | price | balance
-------------------------------
1  | john    | 100   | 40
2  | dave    | 50    | 29
4  | mike    | 482   | 19
```

The query I have so far is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `balance` DESC
```

However this returns all results, and now I have to manually filter the first two out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` is helpful here, if you are using MySQL version 8+:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY balance DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, name, price, balance
FROM cte
WHERE rn >= 3
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

[image]

For earlier versions of MySQL, we can try simulating row number using user variables:

```
SELECT id, name, price, balance
FROM
(
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rn, t.*
    FROM yourTable t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) r
    ORDER BY balance DESC
) t
WHERE rn >= 3
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

### Demo

Comment: What will happen if we have record like below  (1, 'john',   100, 40),
    (2, 'dave',   50,  40),
    (3, 'steven', 29,  200),
    (4, 'mike',   482, 40),
    (5, 'clare',  21,  40);

Comment: sorry about that but OP wants result set to start at the third position, so i was just curious that there might be multiple  third/fourth/fifth   position

Comment: Then the OP wants `RANK`, not `ROW_NUMBER`.  But, I don't know how to simulate rank in MySQL 5.7 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated comparison:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.balance < (select t2.balance
                   from t t2
                   order by t2.balance desc
                   offset 1 limit 1
                  );
```